# Reputation displaying incorrectly on Careers (for some accounts)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, jobs, user-accounts

When I go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/, go to the "Stack Exchange" section, and click on "edit" under "Accounts", I see the following at the bottom of the account list (partially truncated for reasons of space):

[image: reputation displayed on Careers]

Now, as you can see from my reputation here on MSO, I should have the association bonus on all sites where I have an account. Yet, for some reason, my accounts on Android, Italian, Sound Design, and Windows Phone are listed as having just 1 reputation. However, if you look at my account on each of these sites ([Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/46565/user1535629), [Italian](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/278/user1535629), [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/6969/user1535629), and [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/3357/user1535629)), you will see that I do, indeed, have 101 reputation from the association bonus.

At first, I thought the commonality among those four sites was that I hadn't performed any actions on them (not even voting), but it turns out that I have actually cast a vote on Android, so I don't really know what's up.

Note also that all of these accounts are at least a few weeks old (and my association bonus is even older than that), so this doesn't seem like it would be a caching issue or anything.

Comment: Let me have a dev look into this. Last time it took some manual intervention on our part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed - apparently, some accounts will default to 1 before the sync we do between Stack Exchange and Careers. You should be able to add accounts with the correct reputation now.